# Finding out the sum amount from fields that are associated with dates before a given date

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in my database. Now what I want to find out is the total sum amount that are associated with dates before 04-01-2012 from the field "amount".

```
id        Date            Amount
1      02-01-2012          500 
2      03-01-2012          500 
3      04-01-2012          500 
4      25-01-2012          500 
5      10-02-2012          500 
6      21-03-2012          500
```

If I calculate it manually then the result would be: 500( Date: 02-01-2012)+ 500 (Date: 03-01-2012)= 1000.

Would you please kindly help me with the mysql query?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What column type is your `Date` column?

Comment: my date column type is "date". sorry the date format I typed above was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be best:

```
SELECT SUM(`Amount`) AS `Total` FROM `table` WHERE `Date` < DATE('2012-01-04')
```

Will return:

```
Total  
1000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM your_table WHERE `Date` < DATE('04-01-2012')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Sum(Amount) `Total` From table where `Date` < DATE(`04-01-2012`);
```